# Epipolar constraint in the 8-point algorithm

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, projective-geometry

I am developing a system using two cameras, and I want to know is it possible that the epipolar constraint can be satisfied by a matrix that this not part of the set of essential matrices? If so, in which situation do I have to handle this matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A calibrated stereo rig has one well defined (up to scale) [essential matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix) E such that  E = K<sub>1</sub><sup>T</sup> * F * K<sub>2</sub>, where K<sub>1</sub> and K<sub>2</sub> are the camera matrices, and F is the [fundamental matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_%28computer_vision%29). The epipolar constraints determines F, but not E, unless the intrinsic calibration of both cameras is known.

So, to answer your question, as I understand it:

1. Is it possible that the epipolar constraint can be satisfied by a matrix that this not part of the set of essential matrices? Yes, every fundamental matrix for a image pair will satisfy it, but not every fundamental matrix is an essential matrix for a given rig.
2. In which situation do I have to handle this matrix? Probably never: if you are talking about essential matrices, you are in a calibrated setup, which has but one essential matrix (up to scale).

Comment: I don't think this is really answering the question.